# How to create stored procedure with dynamic table names and select content from another table with specific date range?its not working when use java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

Whenevr i m trying to do it in plain sql command then it is working but when i try it throgh java it notworking.only a blank table is created with no data?

```
        DELIMITER $$
        CREATE PROCEDURE `create_tb_tw`(IN tableName varchar(255),IN x varchar(255),IN y varchar(255))
        BEGIN
        SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',tableName,' SELECT * FROM emp
         WHERE hiredate >= ',x,'
         AND hiredate <= ',y);
                PREPARE s FROM @sql;
                EXECUTE s;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
        END $$
        DELIMITER;


        call create_tb_tw("x","'1980-12-17'","'1981-02-22'");//working







    public class emdetails extends HttpServlet {


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

                //db connection

                Connection con = DbConnection.getcon();
                String Sdate = request.getParameter("Sdate");
                String Edate = request.getParameter("Edate");
                String TName = request.getParameter("TName");
                try {
                    CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall("{call create_tb_tw(?, ?,?)}");
                    cStmt.setString(1, TName);
                    cStmt.setString(2, Sdate);  
                    cStmt.setString(3, Edate);
                    cStmt.executeQuery();




                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
    //                System.out.println(emdetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    Logger.getLogger(emdetails.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }
        }

        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletReq`enter code heenter code herere`uest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
         *
         * @param request servlet request
         * @param response servlet response
         * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
         * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
         */
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            processRequest(request, response);
        }

        /**
         * Returns a short description of the servlet.
         *
         * @return a String containing servlet description
         */
        @Override
        public String getServletInfo() {
            return "Short description";
        }// </editor-fold>

    }
```

Whenevr i m trying to do it in plain sql command then it is working but when i try it throgh java it notworking.only a blank table is created with no data?

Comment: And does running the sql command normally without the procedure work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the dates

```
call create_tb_tw("t","'2014-01-01'","'2017-12-31'");
```